# Where is an Outlook Add-In installed?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, outlook, add-in, outlook-addin, outlook-2007

Where can I find my installed AddIn. I've created it in Visual Studio 2010 for Outlook 2007.
Basically I publish and run the setup and cannot find anything on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

Typically (if you have a C: drive) the DLL is in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office\Addins` or `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\{Office Version}\Addins`. There are additional registry entries, but that is the file location.

Comment: Allready looked through that map, there is nothing in there, as the newest file in there is from 2009.
Also looked in almost every \Microsoft Office\ sub directory

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Win7 it's at:
`c:\Users\<CurrentUser>\AppData\Local\assembly\<series of cryptic subfolders>\`

If you're on XP it's at:
`c:\Documents and Settings\<CurrentUser>\Local Settings\Application Data\assembly\<series of cryptic subfolders>\`

Best way to find it is to use your favourite file system search (with "include subfolders" switched on) and search for your DLL by name under `c:\Users\<CurrentUser>` (or `c:\Documents and Settings\<CurrentUser>`).